# SVN tags: How not to update/checkout them?

Tags: svn, tags

In many projects, I check out the complete repository and have then the standard directory structure:

```
project/
    branches/
    tags/
    trunk/
```

If I do an `svn up project`, it's all fine with the `branches` and `trunk` folders, but, of course, the `tags` folder is updated, too, and filled with (mostly) lots of tagged versions that are of no value for my work and only occupy disk space.

How can I except the `tags` folder from an `svn update`? Especially, how can I do this *locally* only, that is, without committing that back to the repository, as a solution with the `svn:ignore` keyword would do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First you check out the top of the project in non recursive way (-N or --non-recursive)

```
svn co https://server/project -N my_project_checkout
```

Now at this stage you can update only the trunk:

```
svn up my_project_checkout/trunk
```

Answer (score 16):

Subversion has a feature called Sparse Checkout for this case.

```
svn up --set-depth empty project/tags
```

This will remove all checked out tags, leaving only the "tags" directory behind.

Another option is:

```
svn up --set-depth immediates project/tags
```

which will check out the tag directories itself, but not their content.
This way you can easily see new tags and get the contents of single tags with:

```
svn up --set-depth infinity project/tags/mytag
```

**Edit:**

This is working with elcucos solution, too and you can even use it for your branches directory.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking out and working in the trunk or on a specific branch. It sounds like you have checked out the entire project tree.

Comment: Actually, yes, I'm checking out the whole thing, since it a) suits my workflow for that specific projects, and b) is easily updateable with a single `svn up` (in contrast to 2 `svn up`s for splitted checkouts). I hoped for a solution with the ability to keep the full repo checked out.

Comment: Ok, but in some case it might be more than you need under `trunk` as well. The question is really is it possible to say that you want only directories 'a', 'b', and 'd', and NOT 'c' ?

Answer (score 1):

To update only specific folder pass them to the svn update command.

```
svn update project/branches project/trunk
```