# Is there any way to update source from SVN except tags?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

As you know, SVN root dir have three sub-dir.(trunk, tags, branches)
And I have a lot of tags in the tags dir.

So when I performed update command with TortoiseSVN on root, It takes a long time And consumes disk space a lot.
Usually I don't need to access tags. Thus, I don't want to update the tags dir.

Is there any way to update sources except the tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to check out the root dir for normal work. If you need trunk, checkout root/trunk.  If you need particular branch, checkout root/branch.  In this case the tags will not be touched on `svn update`.

Comment: Thank you. But I've found better answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855712/svn-tags-how-not-to-update-checkout-them

Comment: Yes, now I see that this is a duplicate question :)